# About the equality $\binom nk + \binom n{k-1} = \binom {n+1}k$

Tags: combinatorics

I was able to get up to the second step, how can I simplify to get to the third step?
$$\eqalign{
\binom nk + \binom n{k-1} & = \dfrac{n!}{(k)!(n-k)!}+\dfrac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!} \\ 
& = \dfrac{n!(n-k+1)+n!k}{k!(n-k+1)!} \\ 
& = \dfrac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!} \\ 
&= \binom {n+1}k.
}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{n!(n-k+1)+n!k}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\dfrac{n!(n-k+1+k)}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\dfrac{n!(n+1)}{k!(n-k+1)!}=\dfrac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k+1)!}$$