Jump statement in induction proof.
This is a follow-up of Stuck in induction proof.. The part that troubles me now is:

$$(a + b)^{m+1} = a^{m+1} + \sum_{k=1}^m \left[ \binom{m}{k} + \binom{m}{k-1} \right] a^{m+1-k} b^k + b^{m+1}$$
$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{m+1}{k} a^{m+1-k} b^k $$

I understand the entire thing except the binomial coefficient addition part. I tried to break it down by factorials but I'm reaching nowhere.
(Also, can someone tell me why it's so hard to type right after the latex formatting?I can't type at all.)

Are you asking why $\binom{m}{k} + \binom{m}{k-1} = \binom{m+1}{k}$? That is the basic recurrence formula for binomial coefficients, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

This is done exactly with breaking into factorials, just check again.

With reference to the comment of Martin R, you can remove the common factor of $~\displaystyle \frac{m!}{(k-1)! ~(m-k)!}~$ from both terms on the LHS and from the RHS term.  The result of removing the common factor then makes the assertion routine to algebraically deal with, for $~m \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k \in {1,2,\cdots,m}.~$  Note that $~0! = 1,~$ by arbitrary convention.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847611, found using https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbinom%20nk%2B%5Cbinom%20n%7Bk-1%7D%3D%5Cbinom%7Bn%2B1%7Dk%24&p=1 Next time, please use Approach0 and/or the search engine of MSE before asking. Btw, here is a link to help you to format your formulas.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491972
